# Check if file has been updated within 10 minutes (CRON)

Tags: php

I want to have a cron that checks if a file has been edited within the last minute but i am not sure on how to do it in that increment.

```
$filename = 'text.txt';
if (file_exists($filename)) {
$lastedit = filemtime($filename);
$date = ('Y-m-d', $lastedit);
$time = strtotime($date);
$unix = time();
if($time == $unix)
DO MY STUFF
}
```

How would i do it more effective?

Comment: Check as `if ($unix - $time < 61)`

Comment: 10 minutes or minute?  You stet one in the title and one in the question.

Comment: Did you give up?

Answer (score 1):

You only need the current timestamp and the file modified timestamp:

```
if(file_exists($filename)) {
    $lastedit = filemtime($filename);
    $unix = time();

    if(($unix - $lastedit) < 600) { //600 for 10min or 60 for 1min
        //DO YOUR STUFF
    }
}
```

Or if you don't need those variables:

```
if(file_exists($filename)) {
    if((time() - filemtime($filename)) < 600) { //600 for 10min or 60 for 1min
        //DO YOUR STUFF
    }
}
```